# Android Studio - How to stop reset to top of ScrollView

Tags: java, android-studio, textview, android-constraintlayout, android-scrollview

I'm currently running a constraint layout in a scrollView and currently have a textView that's pretty far down the screen so I need to scroll down to see it. However, whenever I finish editing the textView that's down the screen (such as changing its constraint by dragging its sides), the screen always resets to the top of the scrollView. Is there a way to prevent this from happening? Sorry if this is confusing, it's a bit hard to explain. Please let me know if any more clarifying details are needed.

**Here's video of the issue:** imgur.com/a/3libvbo

Thanks!

Here's the xml file:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="308dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="322dp">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="BottomOfScrollView"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="1061dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TopOfScrollView"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="112dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="228dp" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
scrollView.postDelayed(new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, textView2.getBottom());
    }
}, 2000);
```

or

```
scrollView.post(new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, textView2.getBottom());
    }
});
```

Expanation:
Calling postDelayed sends runnable to the Handler. after 2 seconds run method is called. ScrollViews have smoothScrollTo(x,y) used to scroll to position. If scroll is horizontal you should use value x, and if it is vertical like in OPs case you scroll on y axis. If you want scrolling to happen without delay use post() instead of postDelayed().

Comment: Please add a little bit of explanation, what this does and why you think it solves OP's problem.

Comment: Please use the Edit feature to add this to your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> However, whenever I finish editing the textView that's down the screen
> (such as changing its constraint by dragging its sides), the screen
> always resets to the top of the scrollView

Its becuase you haven't constraint layout properly

Try this:

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="BottomOfScrollView"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textView2"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="1061dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TopOfScrollView"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Now this layout will make your both text view exactly at the center of layout one below other

Answer (score 0):

Watching your video I can see this is a problem inside of your IDE, not an actual problem of your app.

What's happening here is that everything that's inside a Constraint Layout needs at least 2 constraints, a vertical one (top or bottom) and a horizontal one (left or right).

In your case you've set horizontal constraints to both of your views but not any vertical, so the IDE does not know where to place your view vertically.
If you were to run the app on an emulator, they would fly to top of the Constraint Layout. Every unconstrained view go to the top-left position by default.

So remember: In constraint layours **always** use a vertical and a horizontal constraint (you can use all 4 constraints of course)